# checking multiple email fields in mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a form with multiple 'email' input fields. each is checked in mysql to check if its in the database. what I have now works if an incorrect email is in one of the fields it echo's the right message and if all fields are empty it also echo's the right message. And if the last input field is a correct email it also works. the one problem is that if a correct email address is in one or more of the fields that is not the last one, and there are no other incorrect emails, it will echo "none filled in". I can rectify this by adding a break inside `{$x = "1"}` but then that messes up the mysql check as it needs to continue until/if the condition is not met. is there anything I can do?

```
foreach($_POST as $value)
  {
     if(empty($value))
      {
       $x = "0";
      } else
     if(!empty($value))
      {
        $usercheck =  "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = '$value'";
        $usercheck = $db->query($usercheck);

     if($usercheck->num_rows > 0)
      {
        $x="1";
      } else
        {
          $x="2"; break;
        }
      }
  } 

if($x == "0") {echo "none filled in";}
if($x == "1") {echo "all good";}
if($x == "2") {echo $value." is not a user";}
```

Comment: According to your loop last(Third) value will determine what will echo.. No matter what's in first or second field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$i=1;  
foreach($_POST as $value)
      {
         if(empty($value))
          {
           $x = "0";
          } else
         if(!empty($value))
          {
            $usercheck =  "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = '$value'";
            $usercheck = $db->query($usercheck);

         if($usercheck->num_rows > 0)
          {
            $x="1";
          } else
            {
              $x="2";
            }  
          }
       $field[$i]=$x;
       $i++;
      }
```

Now you have all three field results in `$field` array in 1st, 2nd and 3rd position.